# RPi running script at boot then stops

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, startup, hid

I am running the following program when I boot up my Pi:

```
#This program will scan a bar code and if it matches a good bar code will         flash a light
#green or red depending on the validity of the coupon.

import sys, select, os
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

greenLED = 16
redLED = 12

GPIO.setup(greenLED, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(redLED, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(greenLED, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(redLED, GPIO.LOW)
goodBarCode = "0827112134023"

try:
    #Flash LED to test if script is running at RPi boot

    GPIO.output(greenLED, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(greenLED, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.5)

    while(1):
        print ("Program is running")
        userBarCode = input("")

        if userBarCode == goodBarCode:
            GPIO.output(greenLED, GPIO.HIGH)    
            time.sleep(0.5)
            GPIO.output(greenLED, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(0.5)

        else:
            GPIO.output(redLED, GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            GPIO.output(redLED, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(0.5)

except:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

The objective I am trying to achieve is to turn on the Pi and have this script running and ready to scan barcodes without ever interacting with the Pi. I have successfully added the program to /etc/rc.local and the program begins on boot up. The issue I am having is that it seems to just immediately close the program after printing "Program is running" instead of waiting for an input, any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a

```
raw_input()
```

instead of `input()`. See [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input), what you do is just like `eval(raw_input(""))`. Also, any other details to help you solve? Does it just quit silently?

Comment: I am using python3 isint input() in python3 the same as raw_input() in python2?

Comment: And it seems to quit, when my Pi boots up I will see the "Program is running" line and then instead of waiting for an input, the terminal carrys on as if nothing is running, weather I use the keyboard or barcode scanner.

Comment: whats in $? after the script closes?

Answer (score 0):

Well how do you know the programm really does close?

My guess is: the line:

```
userBarCode = input("")
```

is just waiting for you to type something, and nothing happens before you'll type something.

Comment: No when I type anything the terminal just continues as if nothing is running if I type. I have since added [ userBarCode = input("waiting input") ] to actually see that the input line does run and ti does.

Comment: There is something still unclear: you say you run this script at startup. 1 - Does this script work if you run it from a terminal instead (connected over ssh, I guess)? 2 - When the script is run at startup, where do you see this "Program is running" message? And into which prompt are you able to type anything in to answer the input("")? 3 - I've run a partial version of your script, including the input(""), from command line on my raspi, it works.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/rc.local` is not really the place for that I think. `rc.local` is meant to run things that terminate, your program won't terminate, worse is that your program seems to expect keyboard input.

I would suggest sticking your program in `/etc/inittab` instead.
replace the first line there with your program instead of `/sbin/getty 38400 tty1`

```
#
# Note that on most Debian systems tty7 is used by the X Window System,
# so if you want to add more getty's go ahead but skip tty7 if you run X.
#
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
2:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty2
3:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty3
4:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty4
5:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty5
6:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty6
```